# Как удалять класс при изменении ширины экрана на jQuery?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, menu

У меня есть меню, которое открывается при нажатии на кнопку, и также закрывается. Также, с помощью медиа запроса сделал так, чтобы при изменении экрана меню скрывалось. То есть, если ширина экрана больше 800px, меню получает "**display: none;**".

Но если меню было открыто, оно не закроется, а просто получит "**display: none;**". В момент перехода с ширины 801px на 800px и ниже, оно появляется сразу же открытым, так как display становится flex.

Чтобы исправить это нужно сделать так, чтобы в момент перехода с 800px на 801px и больше, елемент не просто получал "**display: none;**", нужно чтобы удалялся класс у елемента. Как это сделать?

```
@media (min-width: 801px) {
  .mobile-menu-active {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```
const mediaQueryMin = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 800px)')


if (mediaQuery.matches) {
  navButton.on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    mobileMenu.toggleClass('mobile-menu-active');
    $('.burger-menu--close').toggleClass('burger-menu--close-active')
    $('.burger-menu--menu').toggleClass('burger-menu--menu-disable')
  });
} else {
    mobileMenu.removeClass('mobile-menu-active');
}
```

И вот код, которым я хотел удалить класс, но он почему-то не работает:

```
function menuRemoveClass() {
  if($(window).width() > 800) {
    $('.mobile-menu').removeClass('.mobile-menu-active');
  }
}

$(window).resize(function(){
  menuRemoveClass();
})
```

Comment: он не работает, потому что removeClass('mobile-menu-active') пишется без точки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде как решил:

```
function menuRemoveClass() {
  if($(window).width() > 800) {
    $('.mobile-menu').removeClass('mobile-menu-active');
    $('.burger-menu--menu').removeClass('burger-menu--menu-disable')
    $('.burger-menu--close').removeClass('burger-menu--close-active')
  }
}

$(window).resize(function(){
  menuRemoveClass();
})
```

Я не убрал точку (исправил), а также для правильной работы удалил классы с кнопок. Вроде как теперь работает, но возможно у вас будь решения поудонее.

Comment: В данном решении есть небольшой минус. Вызов функции будет срабатывать при изменении экрана даже на 1 пиксель. А это в свою очередь будет нагружать клиентскую машину. Попробуйте воспользоваться `@media`-query и пропишите нужные Вам стили для данных классов под соответствующее разрешение экрана.